How to define interface for prisma model
I want to create a function that have arg is prisma model like bellow
function functionName(model) {

  / /do something with this model
}

how can I add typescript for model without known the list of model something like this
function functionName<T>(model : PrismaModel<T>) {

  / /do something with this model
}

functionName<PrismaClient['user']>(prisma.user)

